# Javascript calling the class method in another script tag fails in IE

Tags: javascript

In my html code I have imported an external js file and also have my own inline js code, and in my own js code I need to call the method of an object defined in the external js file. After rendering, the source code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // content of the extenral js file
  ...
  var bar = {};
  bar.foo = {};
  ...
  bar.foo.class = {};
  bar.foo.class.method = function() {...};
  ...
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // content of my own javascript code
  ...
  function load() {
    ...
    bar.foo.class.method();
    ...
  }
  ...
</script>
```

For the framework I'm using I cannot make the two parts in one place (i.e. either both are in the external js file or both are in my own inline js code). Now, this code works in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari but not works in IE. The IE debugger shows an error like: "Unable to get value of the property 'foo': object is null or undefined"

It looks like either the bar.foo.class defined in the first tag is not visible to the second tag, or the second tag is executed before the first tag (first tag is all about class definition, no real workflow).

Does anyone know how to work around this in IE? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..may be visibility problem..... I think it will work

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // content of the extenral js file
      ...
      var bar = {};
      bar.foo = {};
      ...
      bar.foo.class = {};
      bar.foo.class.method = function() {...};
      ...
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // content of my own javascript code
var _bar = bar; 
      ...
      function load() {
        ...
        _bar.foo.class.method();
        ...
      }
      ...
    </script>
```

Another option.. Avoid to use var keyword then it will be global

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          // content of the extenral js file
          ...
          bar = {};
          bar.foo = {};
          ...
          bar.foo.class = {};
          bar.foo.class.method = function() {...};
          ...
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          // content of my own javascript code
          ...
          function load() {
            ...
            bar.foo.class.method();
            ...
          }
          ...
        </script>
```

Comment: The first one doesn't work. The second one doesn't work either. But one interesting thing is that if I use your second code, the error info would be "bar is undefined". Note that in my own code the error code is "unable to get the value of property 'foo': null or undefined". I think this suggest that the variable 'bar' is recognized  by the code in the second tag, but not it's property 'foo'. Maybe we can look at why foo is not recognized rather than bar... But I'm still not sure how to fix this...

Comment: I tried to alert(bar). In IE it shows "undefined", and in all others it shows "{object, object}". So I think the problem is still that 'bar' defined in the first tag is not recognized by the code in the second tag...

Answer (score 0):

The word `class` is a reserved word. Use something else like `klass` or do something like `foo["class"]`.

Comment: Sorry class is not the real name in my code, just as an example... And you mean using foo["class"] in the second tag (i.e. when calling it) or in the first tag (i.e. when defining it)?